# How to use small random integer generator to make a big one?

Tags: random-variables

If we have a random integer generator (like a dice: $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$) with a few possible outcomes, is there a way to generate a uniformly distributed with more possible outcomes?(for example: $\{1,2,3,4,\dots,100\}$)

I think I should group bigger set into groups with same number of members and choose between them? Like:

$\{1,2,...,36\} \Rightarrow \{\{1,\dots,6\},\{7,\dots,12\},\dots,\{31,\dots,36\}\}$
random number one $= 3 \Rightarrow \{13,14,15,16,17,18\}$
random number two $= 2 \Rightarrow \{14\}$

But is there any mathematical operation $(+,/,*,-,\log, \dots)$ to do with random number one and two?

Comment: Have you heard of acceptance / rejection sampling?

Comment: You can use a hash function. One property of the hash functions is that the function perform a uniform distribution of the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that what you want is 6((random 1)-1) + (random 2 -1).

What you want to do is use the results of consecutive rolls to produce a string (e.g. 1546). Subtract one from every value to get a number in base 6. (e.g. 0435). Then, convert it to base 10, e.g. $5 + 3\times 6 + 4\times 6^2 + 0 \times 6^3$. You can check this is a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have one die, and you are trying to generate a random number from $1 .. N$

You can at least divide the numbers into two sets, odd and even. If you roll an even, call it 0 and if you roll an odd call it 1. In this way you can generate a random binary string of arbitrary length. Now roll it $\log_2 N + 1$ times. If the resulting binary number is $\le N$ then you accept that as the outcome. If not, start over.

By no means is this the most efficient way to generate this distribution but it just shows it's possible.